# Center Align with CSS Grid

Tags: css, alignment

I've got a button `class="view-more"` that I'm trying to center align on the page within my div `class="main"` but I just cannot get it to move.

I've tried the align-self, content, and items along with justify options but it just stays at the bottom left of the div.

I think my positions might be causing the issue but I'm not sure. I'm still learning and those are throwing me off.

Here is the full main code.

```css
main {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  height: 1060px;
}

main .videos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}

main .videos img {
  height: 240px;
  width: 92%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 24px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

main a {
  position: relative;
}

main .videos h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  color: var(--light-color);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

main .videos h4 span {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

main .videos i {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 30%;
  left: 40%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 100px;
}

main .view-more {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--dark-color);
  color: var(--hightlight-color);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h3>Featured Videos</h3>
    <div class="videos">
        <h4><span>Hands // Tobias Levin</span></h4>
        <h4><span>Rise // Virtuoso</span></h4>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQLhO7dW5ZY" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/tobias1.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7kG641iA_g" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/rise.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h4><span>This is Dan and Dave</span></h4>
        <h4><span>Super // Chris Webber</span></h4>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBRkiXlW_kM" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/dand.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lyf_SsOThMs" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/cwebber.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h4><span>Superhuman // Brian Tudor</span></h4>
        <h4><span>Smoke Screen // Jaspas Deck</span></h4>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qU0I8BnwoFk" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/bt.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Wk3imz44qI" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/smokescreen.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <button class="view-more">Open The Vault</button>
</main>
```

Comment: We cannot infer the problem just with CSS, you need to include HTML code as well in your question

Comment: Add the css and html in a single snippet. Otherwise, we won't be able to see the css in work.

Comment: Approved edit, sorry I don't really know how to use this site very well.

Comment: Why do you mix grid-template and position:absolute?  Grid can do the job if you set children in the right cells.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks for pointing this out, I'm still learning so I get a bit confused around all the elements at times. I gave it some thought and added the button back into the grid main and just justified-self along with 2 column span and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind if the title/everything in the main container is centered? If not, you can simply add text-align center to the container which would center the children. The problem with your code not moving the button is because you added "position absolute" to the button, meaning it will not center relative to its parent, but rather to the window. I removed that position absolute, and the button will now listen to its parent. Does that make sense?

```css
main {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  height: 1060px;
  text-align: center;
}

main .videos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}

main .videos img {
  height: 240px;
  width: 92%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 24px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

main a {
  position: relative;
}

main .videos h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  color: var(--light-color);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

main .videos h4 span {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

main .videos i {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 30%;
  left: 40%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 100px;
}

main .view-more {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--dark-color);
  color: var(--hightlight-color);
}
```

```html
<main>
                <h3>Featured Videos</h3>
                <div class="videos">
                    <h4><span>Hands // Tobias Levin</span></h4>
                    <h4><span>Rise // Virtuoso</span></h4>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQLhO7dW5ZY" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/tobias1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7kG641iA_g" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/rise.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <h4><span>This is Dan and Dave</span></h4>
                    <h4><span>Super // Chris Webber</span></h4>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBRkiXlW_kM" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/dand.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lyf_SsOThMs" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/cwebber.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <h4><span>Superhuman // Brian Tudor</span></h4>
                    <h4><span>Smoke Screen // Jaspas Deck</span></h4>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qU0I8BnwoFk" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/bt.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Wk3imz44qI" class="fresco"><i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-7x"></i><img src="/images/smokescreen.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <button class="view-more">Open The Vault</button>
            </main>
```

Comment: I removed the position: absolute on the button and added the text-align you mentioned but now I cannot find the button at all.

With the position: absolute on it did align it but not in the center it was too far off to the right.

Comment: @FrocketGaming Hello, sorry I haven't been active on the site. Happy thanksgiving! Were you able to find a solution? It seems weird the button would disappear unless you have other elements with position absolute that would interfere. EDIT:: Disregard my comment, I saw you got a solution working in the comments above!